# Lengths of a Circle

Tags: geometry

> $n=6$ points are equally spaced around a circle of radius one. Three of these points are the vertices of a scalene triangle. What is the area of this triangle?

I don't know where to start, I tried drawing a graph but it didn't get me anywhere. I suppose I *could* try every combination, but that will take an **extremely** long time and I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: If six points are equally spaces on the circle, they make up the vertices of what regular polygon?  What grouping of three points would you have to choose to guarantee that the three sides of the triangle _all have different lengths_?  How can you use trigonometry to give you the distances between pairs of those points? What formula can you use to find the area of the triangle?  (This is probably not the only way to proceed.)

Comment: @boojum I haven't learned trigonometry yet :( This is coming from an Intro to Geometry course.

Comment: You don't need trig:  once you find the correct grouping, you can get one of the sides from what you know about the circle and an adjacent side from the geometry of the polygon.  Notice that there is a congruent triangle that can be formed with one of the other possible groupings that will form a rectangle with the triangle you made.  The area of the triangle is then half the area of that rectangle.  (That avoids any knowledge of trigonometry.)

Comment: @boojum Yes, but you said in your comment "How can you use trigonometry to give you the..."

Comment: The way I describe in the second comment avoids that; I didn't know originally that you hadn't learned trig yet.  In fact, I just noticed that you can prove by geometry (using one of the circle-chord theorems) that the scalene triangle is a _right_ triangle for which you will have one side and the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 3 unique triangles (up to rotation and translation) that can be drawn with vertices at 3 of these points. The first is an equilateral triangle with points that all have a gap of 1 point between each other. This creates an alternating pattern of points that are or are not vertices around the circle. So, to get a non-equilateral triangle, there need to be at least 2 consecutive vertices in the triangle. Any 2 consecutive points work. From here, there are only 2 more triangles we can create: the 3 vertices can be consecutive, creating an isosceles triangle, or the third vertex can be across the circle from the first 2, creating a scalene triangle. From here, simply calculate the area.

Answer (score 2):

Create an Inscribed Hexagon of side length $a = r\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, with this Hexagon you can create $\dfrac{6}{2} = 3$ rectangle with side $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, x$ and diagonal $d = 2r = 2$,

with a side and diagonal, another side $x$ can be found :

$x = \sqrt{2^2 - a^2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$

Each of these rectangles contain 2 of those scalene triangles (it will be scalene because all side of rectangle including diagonal is different). So in total there will be 6 same scalene triangle inside this Hexagon.

The area of the triangle can then be found using the area of that rectangle earlier (side $x$ and $a$)

Comment: Thanks, this solution seems like it works, but I have not learned trigonometry yet, so I don't fully understand it.

Comment: If you dont understand it yet, then just use Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is a diagram to clarify my comments.  There are not many possible triangles that can be formed once allowance is made for the symmetry of the regular hexagon.  If any two consecutive vertices of the hexagon are chosen, there are two choices left for a third vertex that makes a scalene triangle, and one of those is just an inverted version of the other (again because of the overall symmetry).  Starting with vertices separated by one, there are two choices for making a scalene triangle, but those are also congruent to the ones already described.  Taking diametrically-opposite vertices leads to four congruent scalene triangles.  So all of the possible options always produce a scalene congruent to the one shown.

The only length information we are given are for the radii in red.  The geometry of the regular hexagon lets us find the side of the triangle in question, and we know the diameter of the circle.  There are (at least) two ways to make geometrical arguments (without the use of trigonometry) to find all of the angles in question.  Once we know *what kind* of scalene triangle this is, we have enough information to find the length of the remaining side of the triangle, and hence its area.

**ADDENDUM:**  Gah!  Looking at the diagram again this morning, I realized I got entirely too fixated on finding some of those angles.  With the *right* circle-chord theorem, you can get the angle of the triangle opposite the diameter of the circle and go on to find the area rather quickly.